# Как разархивировать zip архив?

Tags: android

Добрый вечер.

Подскажите, кто знает, как правильно распаковать архив. У меня извлекает из трех файлов только один. Где у меня ошибка? Спасибо!

```
public void decompress(String zipFile) throws IOException {
        try {
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                File unzipFile = new File(directory,ze.getName());
                String path = unzipFile.getAbsolutePath();
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path, false);
                try {
                    for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                        fout.write(c);
                    }
                    zin.closeEntry();
                }
                finally {
                    fout.close();
                }
            }
                zin.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }   }
```

Comment: ну попробуйте другой готовый метод, в гугле их полным-полно. Если один не сработал, попробуйте другой просто.

Comment: А где именно ошибка? Я вижу, что передаётся параметром всего один файл. Или это папка? Что такое directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что такое directory? Глобальная переменная? Есть ли предупреждения от отладчика?
Предположу, что распаковывается только последний по списку файл. Так ли это?

```
  File unzipFile = new File(directory+ze.getName());
```

[Доки на File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Полагаю, вам нужен  "public File(String pathname)", а не "public File(String parent,String child)"

Теперь по поводу: FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path, false);
[Доки.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)
На сколько я понимаю, если будет ошибка здесь

```
try {
                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                    fout.write(c);
                }
```

то

```
finally {
                fout.close();
            }
```

не выполнится и поток не закроется. Т.к. у вас в параметрах созданного потока стоит false, в следующей итерации цикла будет записываться с начала.

Попробуйте сделать, как [здесь](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-programmatically-zip-and-unzip-file-in-android). Раздел "How to UnZip files".